# "Immersive Mode" Android app. All documentation is deprecated

Tags: android, windows, kotlin

I'm trying to make my app run in fullscreen mode where the navigation bar and the status bar is hidden. All documentation I can find seems to be deprecated and the only one that I could find that seemed to not be deprecated in **Kotlin** is `setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)` but that errors with

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method setDecorFitsSystemWindows(Z)V in class Landroid/view/Window; or its super classes (declaration of 'android.view.Window' appears in /system/framework/framework.jar!classes3.dex)
```

How do you make an app fullscreen now in Android Kotlin?

Comment: If you follow the documentation, it's not deprecated: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/immersive

Comment: @Tenfour04 Oh not deprecated yet... Looks like I'm in API level 10+ while my actual phone is just 10. That might be the issue.

Comment: Do you mean Android 10 (API 29)? But immersive mode is not deprecated, never has been deprecated, and is not deprecated in the upcoming Android 11.

Comment: It says that SystemUiVisibility flags were deprecated in Andriod API 30. I have a Samsung phone with android version 10 which I'm guessing is API level 29. I'm not even sure if what I put is the right way to code the app in immersive mode. @Tenfour04

Comment: Oh if it says that, I missed it in the release notes. The documentation for deprecated methods always instructs you on what to do instead. But i suggest making your targetSdkVersion 29 for now.

Comment: I don't know what solution you went for but for now, I've added an if-else to check if it's Android R or above, use `setDecorFitsSystemWindows` else use `System_UI_Flag`. This is very new, couldn't found any thing else except your question.

Comment: getting same error, have you found a fix?

Comment: Just use `WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(window, false)` instead of `window.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)`. The new APIs are for devices using Android 11. You need the backported compat version to make this work on older versions.

Answer (score 5):

There are one alternative solution.

**Update androidx.core library**

```
implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0-alpha05"
```

Instead of

```
activity?.window?.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(false)
```

Use new api

```
activity?.window?.run{
     WindowCompat.setDecorFitsSystemWindows(this, false)
}
```